# How to authenticate web service call that uses Facebook to authenticate users?

Tags: iphone, web-services, authentication, rest, facebook

I'm developing an iOS app that uses Facebook authentication for a user to log into the app, the app then interacts with a Python REST web service.

What strategy should I use to authenticate the web service call once the user has signed into the app using their Facebook credentials?

Comment: do you own the Python REST web service?

Comment: Yeah, I should clarify, I want my users to log into the app using Facebook authentication and then store/retrieve some data related to their account in my database using a REST service.

Answer (score 6):

Send the auth token to your REST web service and let the REST web service check it with fb (facebook).

1. Once the user has signed into the app you get an authentication token.
2. Send the token and the fb user id to you REST web service.
3. Your web service should verify that the token is valid (this involves an server-server api call to fb).

   I used php and this code but python should kinda look the same.

   ```
   function checkFacebookLogin($acces_token) {
       $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" . strip_tags($acces_token);
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
       $response = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       $user = json_decode($response);
       return $user;
   }
   ```
4. If it's valid you get back a user.
5. Verify the user id's (from fb and from the post in step 2). If it's the same you've got yourself an authenticated user.
6. Store the authentication token and a timestamp in you local database on you server so you don't have to make a call to facebook over ander over again. When the user re-logs-in you could check the authentication token and the time (valid for only x hours) and grant permission without checking the token with facebook. Be warned that the user may revoked fb permissions in the meantime btw.

Good luck.

#### Update for commented question:

Of course, check out [validating the token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken) from google's developer doc's. It's written for a (javascript like) client app but that does not matter. You can just call the url with php or python.

In the end you will call something like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=##ADD_TOKEN_HERE##
```

You could also read those 2 docs from Google about logging in with google from an installed app and conning with google from a webserver.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: That's the great anwser, I was looking for. Maybe you know whether something like that (auth verification using `../me?access_token=xxx`) is also possible with Google/OpenID?

Answer (score 3):

Workflow that I would take:

1. Authenticate user with facebook
2. Retrieve access token from facebook
3. Pass facebook authentication token back to web-service
4. Get Facebook user info by access token i.e. facebook userId, email, etc.
5. Verify user details with your local user db
6. if user exists log user in from server-end (or treat user as a logged in user)
7. if its a new user register user and log user in
8. do rest...

Basically it is a very similar approach like facebook API. You will always have a accesstoken padding (query string) at the end of your url. 
Good thing about this one, is you don't need to worry about access token expiry anymore.

Comment: That's the great anwser, I was looking for. Maybe you know whether something like that (auth verification using `../me?access_token=xxx`) is also possible with Google/OpenID?

Comment: I think so, this work flow should apply to similar token-based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

#### Authenticating a User

Here is the official Facebook documentation on how to authenticate users using the `Facebook SDK` on the `iOS` platform: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/authenticate/

Here is a link to the Facebook's official `xcode` sample on GitHub which allows you to authenticate users using the `FBSession` object: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SessionLoginSample. This code will work on `iPhone OS 4.0 or later`.

In order to get started with this code sample you will need to go through the [following six steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) to get started using the `Facebook SDK`:

- Install [Xcode 4.5](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
- Install the [Facebook SDK for iOS](https://github.com/downloads/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/FacebookSDK-3.1.1.pkg) or via Git: `git clone git@github.com:facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git FacebookSDK`
- Find the `SessionLoginSample` sample in the samples directory in the SDK
- Create a new app here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and note down the `app ID`
- Start a new Xcode project and:

> Add the Facebook SDK for iOS Framework by dragging the
>   `FacebookSDK.framework` folder from the SDK installation folder into the
>   `Frameworks` section of your `Project Navigator`.
>
> Add the Facebook SDK for iOS resource bundle by dragging the
>   `FacebookSDKResources.bundle` file from the
>   `FacebookSDK.framework/Resources` folder into the `Frameworks` section of
>   your `Project Navigator`.
>
> Next you need to add the `''-lsqlite3.0''` SQL library to the list of
>   build dependencies in the Build Settings pane

- Add in your `app ID` in the following places:

> You need to place the Facebook app ID in two places in your
>   application's main `.plist` file. Create a key called `FacebookAppID`
>   with a string value, and add the app ID there.
>
> Also, create an array key called URL types with a single array
>   sub-item called URL Schemes. Give this a single item with your `app
>   ID` prefixed with fb.

The [six detailed steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/) you shall find here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

#### Retrieving User Data

After a user has been authenticated i.e. after an `activeSession` on `FBSession` has been opened, you need to use the Facebook SDK `FBRequest` object to get the user's information as a `FBGraphUser` object which you can send to your Python REST web service. The official tutorial for this is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/personalize/ and the related code sample is `ProfilePictureSample` found here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/ProfilePictureSample

The `FBGraphUser` object only has a [limited set of data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#external_profile) it can return, namely:

- Title - Profile Name
- Description - Description of Profile Object
- Image - Array of images
- URL - Open Graph URL of the Profile
- First Name - First Name of Profile
- Last Name - Last Name of Profile
- Username - Username of Profile, if applicable
- Gender - male or female
- Profile ID - Facebook user id

Full list of Open Graph object data is here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-objects/#external_profile

Any questions, please feel free to leave some comments.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to provide separate authenticate solution for your REST service, as long as you would allow people to do CUD (create, update, delete) on your own data, instead of just R (read).

Speaking of that, to go with standard or more of trend, oAuth 1.0 (Twitter) or 2.0 (Facebook) are the best bet. oAuth 1.0 is bit of complicated, but oAuth 2.0 requires SSL. Amazon AWS has it's own approach solving the authentication problem, you can study it a bit to see if that's what you want. But in general, if your REST service is designed to be available for 3rd-party developers, better go with the standard.

Answer (score 0):

oAuth2.0, the Facebook-friendly version of oAuth, is your best bet. Facebook's *Graph API* has sole support of it, and because of that, will be easier and/or safer than using some other work-around. The incorporated status of oAuth2.0 with the Facebook foundational Graph API leaves me to recommend that oAuth2.0 is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Facebook oAuth implement api.

First you need to register to Facebook for using oauth. 
Facebook will provide you tokens (basic unique string id).

Using these token you will invoke login service of Facebook.

On successfully attempt you will get some user data and a callback to redirect the control to your application.

For example you can ref sample  oauth based twitter service. 
http://shakthydoss.com/open-authentication-oauth-with-twitter/